# When I cross data from a slow clock to a fast clock domain, wouldn't the stretched data be an issue for processing?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, clock, fifo

I want to use two fifo's asynchronously in series to cross from a slow-clock domain to a fast-clock domain.

I have a slow clock (x MHz) that I need a multiple of (either 2x, 3x, 4x, or 6x). I won't have an issue with overflow on the first fifo since the next fifo will be set to a faster clock.

However, wouldn't this be an issue for the next component receiving the data?

I am assuming the data would be stretched. For example, if I did a 2x multiple of the clock. I start with 4-bit data: "0011". Would I receive 8-bits: "00001111" or only a portion of the original data: "1111"?

If I programmed the array of memory to be 4 bits, then wouldn't my fifo overflow? Do I have to write a custom fifo to ignore every other bit? I don't want to rely on wait for.

This is the [vhdl tutorial](https://youtu.be/bYXBTAhNLIk) I followed. It seemed like a pretty standard fifo with few lines of HDL code.

Comment: You might consider a single dual clock FIFO for crossing clock domains. See [A DUAL-CLOCK FIFO FOR THE RELIABLE TRANSFER OF HIGH-THROUGHPUT DATA BETWEEN UNRELATED CLOCK DOMAINS](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.295.3122&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Simulation and Synthesis Techniques for Asynchronous FIFO Design with Asynchronous Pointer Comparisons](https://github.com/cxhy/asyn_fifo/blob/master/doc/alfke_final.pdf).  Also [Understanding clock domain crossing issues](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279906).

Comment: Cross domains communication is a complex problem and you do not provide enough information for us to really help you. Indeed, there is no universal solution. All solutions are based on particular relations between the clocks, the data... Are your two clocks derived one from the other (or from a third one)? If yes, how are they synchronous? Are their rising edges perfectly aligned? Unaligned but by a fixed skew? Which skew? Are they drifting? Do your data come from a register clocked on rising edges of the slow clock? What is the delay between the data and its clock?

Comment: Last but not least, you should probably clearly state in your question that your data is serial (one bit).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dual clock FIFO for the clock domain crossing to avoid the problem you describe as well as metastability and other problems.

The links in the comments on your questions are a good place to start.